# “Variable is never assigned” warning in IntelliJ IDEA can be suppressed only "partially"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-inspection, unused-variables

Java EE + IntelliJ Idea 2016.3: I've written a class and declared a private field with a `@Inject` annotation.

I have successfully got rid of the "unused declaration" notification from the "inspection results" window by adding `javax.inject.Inject` to *settings -> editor -> inspections -> Java -> declaration redundancy -> unused declarations -> entry points -> annotations -> mark field as implicitly written when annotated by* (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762012/suppress-variable-is-never-assigned-warning-in-intellij-idea)).

Unfortunately the field is still underlined and a yellow marker is present on the scroll bar. Do I configure this separately or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Show us the code, please.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There are two separate warnings. One says the field was **never assigned** a value, which is the one you have disabled. The other says the field was **never used**, which is the warning you are getting.

Add `Inject` to *settings -> editor -> inspections -> java -> declaration redundancy -> unused declarations -> entry points -> annotations -> Mark as entry point if annotated by*

Comment: Adding the `@Inject` annotation to the "mark as entry point" section instead the "mark field as implicitly written" did the job. However, before I did that the warning message was `Private field 'logger' is never assigned` and not **never used** as you said. I *am* using the `logger` field later in the code. Simultaneously the code inspector reported "No suspicious code found" - maybe it is a bug in Idea.

Comment: Also note that Alt-Enter provides menu entries to how to turn warnings off.

Comment: "Alt-Enter provides menu entries to how to turn warnings off" - yes, but in my idea it only directs to "unused declaration". one has to know to click into "entry points" and "annotations"

Comment: In my case, I had Spring Value annotation, and I had to add it to the subsection "Mark field as explicitly written if annotated by".

Answer (score 35):

Highlight the field, type Alt + Enter "Windows" or  ⌥⏎ "Mac" or Just click on the Light Bulb. Select the "Suppress for fields annotated by {annotation name}.

Comment: I do not have this option in IDEA 2019.1.2 (Ultimate Edition). Where can I find this option now?

Comment: same here. With light bulb I only see other stuff (Add consturctor parameters, change access modifiert, ..) but no supression
2022.3.1 (Community Edition)

Comment: found it, see my response below were I could add a picture: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75334658/3276902

Answer (score 10):

You can just choose to ignore it in some cases where it actually make sense,

[image]

What you can do is hover the affected area and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Enter</kbd> in "Windows" or <kbd>alt/option/⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in "Mac", **and chose to suppress it**.

You'll see,

[image]

Comment: I had used this in the past but totally forgot how to bring this dialogue :D. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: I think it's kinda irritating that it says "suppress *unused* warning..." but it's in fact the "never assigned warning".

Answer (score 6):

It seems that it was a bug in IDEA. I've just updated to IDEA **2016.3.1** and now `@Inject` and `@Resource` annotations put in the "entry points" section do not work - they have to be put in the "fields" window (although when they are in "entry points" section I can still observe the "old" behavior i.e. annotated fields are not detected by code inspection yet they are underlined in the editor and yellow marker is visible).

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2023**

I had this issue before, but the screens look different now:

- I don't have `Suppress unused warning if annotated...`
- Now, it is `Assume fields annotated by ...@Autowired as implicitly written`

The first option didn't appear.
I had to select the variable name, instead of the type.

[image: Context Actions Dialog]