# Eclipse with SonarLint crashes with OutOfMemory working on specific problematic classes

Tags: eclipse, jvm, sonarlint

I'm working with eclipse on Windows 7 and after [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49065177/eclipse-missing-warning-if-variable-used-before-assigned) suggested SonarLint for catching problematic code, I installed it and it's working fine (99%).

I now have an issue with specific legacy classes with too many sonar issues (10K lines of bad code).

Eclipse keeps crashing when working on this files, `OutOfMemoryError` exception in log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-05-14 15:10:40.524
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2018-05-14 15:10:40.526
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "SonarLint analysis of file MyJava.java".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-05-14 15:10:51.220
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:903)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I didn't find way to exclude files in sonarlint plugin.

Is there a way still working with SonarLint and handling such files or is there a different approach/plugin?

I tried adding `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` but it didn't helped. another configuration:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in the right direction. We also have Uber files containing more then 10K lines of code in our projects/CRs.

The solution in our case was simple - increase the JVM max heap size to 4GB:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx4096m
```

This solved the probelm for a 13K bad code file that was the cause of the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception on our end (using Eclipse Oxygen).

Alterntive solutions? You can [configure SonarLint not to scan automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795619/disable-sonarlint-automatic-scan-for-eclipse-remote-systems-explorer) each Java class which you open in the editor. This way you can manually select your scans and avoid the large file scans.

I recommend increasing the heap size to 4GB, then again my workstation has 16GB of memory.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check in a few days

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem for me with Eclipse 4.13.0 and a project with some 7000 source files.

Comment: @DavidPursehouse : Very happy I could help. Take care buddy.

Comment: Apparently -Xmx2048m was not enough - -Xmx4096m did the trick